# How can I disable all "Ubuntu sounds"?

Tags: sound

Sometimes Ubuntu issues sounds for certain events. For example, when a user logs out, Ubuntu plays a short drum beat snippet.

These "sounds" are nice quality. But I need a "soundless" sound profile to prevent any noise when I operate in quiet environments. How can I prevent Ubuntu from issuing any sounds? With Microsoft Windows, I can just select a "No Sound" profile.

I tried Sound > Sound Effects > Alert Volume = Mute. but this does nothing.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the speaker icon and then selecting mute?

Comment: This mutes the sound of everything, like the speech from a lecture playing in VLC. I want to mute just the sounds originating from the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Does your setting Alert Volume = Mute actually mute some of your sounds? On that same menu, try clicking on the word "Default" under alert sounds. Does it make a beep when Mute is not selected and is silent when mute is selected?

Comment: James: 1) Yes, when I mute Alert Volume it works to mute sound when I click Default. So it is working--thanks for pointing this out. 2) I don't want to install Tweak. Seems like a way should exist to do this without having to install something.

Comment: The answer I posted involved installing Ubuntu Tweak, but have you tried just clicking the mute button on the login screen? It should mute the login sound but once logged in your user's sound should not be muted.

Comment: Clicking the mute button worked to block login sound. You should put this as an installation-free answer James.

Answer (score 22):

On Ubuntu 14.04, running this command solved it for me instantly:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/event-sounds false
```

Comment: am I not understanding something here ? 2 upvotes to a separate answer that describes disabling sound via plugging in a dummy jack to audio socket. Here is van actual clear solution... +1, thanks

Comment: Works still (for me at least) on 20.04

Comment: Does it need a restart or something? Because it didn't work for me.

Comment: @SaeedNeamti: It still works instantly for me. Maybe your desktop environment (e.g. KDE) ignores this setting.

Answer (score 5):

## **To mute the Alert Sounds along with the login/logout sounds:**

---

### **Using Ubuntu Tweak**

Install Ubuntu Tweak

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

Once installed, launch it and select Tweaks, then Sounds to make your selections:

[image]

[image]

---

### **Without using Ubuntu Tweak**

Open the Sound Menu in System

[image]

[image]

[image]

This will diasable the Alert Sounds. To also disable the login sound we first have to make Gnome Login Sound visable in startup Applications. To do this, open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) and enter:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome/autostart/libcanberra-login-sound.desktop`

In the gedit window that opens, change the line that reads "NoDisplay=true" to "NoDisplay=false".

[image]

Open your Startup Applications through the Dash and then make sure Gnome Login Sound is unslected:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Disabling Gnome Login Sounds does not work for later versions of Ubuntu. For that you can disable the login sounds by Muting the sound at the login screen. However, sometimes this transfers over to the user making you have to un-mute when logged in. But it will stick in the login screen.*

Comment: Muting the Login-screen worked, James. Thanks. I don't want to install Ubuntu Tweak. But it'd be great to be able to mute each Tweak item without installing Tweak. How can I create a new sound theme that mutes all system sounds to replace the "Ubuntu sound theme"?

Comment: Updated answer to include ways to do it without Ubuntu Tweak.

Comment: Too bad ubuntu-tweak isn't part of the standard repos for Ubuntu 16.04 :-/

Answer (score 2):

Like you I like a silent computer & I dislike the Ubuntu drum sound on start-up & reboot.

My solution to silence my computer was to get an old set of headphones, or ones that no longer work, and cut off the cord at the headphone jack and place the remaining headphone jack in the headphone socket on the computer. When you want to listen to sounds take out the silencing headphone jack.

It's crude and a software/system setting solution would be better, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

The Sound Preferences dialog is a bit mysterious since not everything has an obvious effect.

There are, however, a couple of things that seem to be useful here:

- Set the "Sound theme" to "No sounds"
- Disable the checkbox for "Enable window and button sounds"

---

- Open the dialog in Ubuntu MATE: `System->Preferences->Sound`
- Open the dialog from the MATE command line: `mate-volume-control`
- Just guessing, but this might be `gnome-volume-control` when not using MATE desktop

[image: Sound Preferences dialog]

Answer (score 0):

[Another way](https://opensourceinside.blogspot.in/2017/02/disablingchanging-drum-beat-sound-on.html) is to get rid of the `ogg` file itself. Go to `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo` and replace the `system-ready.ogg` file with a [silence.ogg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Silence.ogg) file which you can shorten with [Audacity](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjq_uPNw-PXAhWJs48KHbezCEQQFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.audacityteam.org%2Fdownload%2F&usg=AOvVaw3usmD3ZGfu7IwgPNYPPj5J).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04 what I did to resolve this issue is:

```
❯ cd /usr/share/sounds/Yaru/stereo
❯ sudo mv power-unplug.oga power-unplug.oga_removed
❯ sudo mv power-plug.oga power-plug.oga_removed
```

This is the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes Ubuntu sound configuration just not working...
For example the alert sound is too noisy and annoying and sometimes it makes error or occurs lagging but whatever I changing in sound setting, it never works.

If you want to turn off completely every sound from Ubuntu than you can just remove `pulseaudio`.

```bsh
sudo apt purge pulseaudio
```

And if you want to turn on sound later, than just reinstall the `pulseaudio`.

```bsh
sudo apt install pulseaudio
```

Comment: But it's not a good choice to uninstall all pulseaudio if you want to disable sounds.

Comment: This seems rather excessive as it would make watching videos dull and listening to music impossible.

Comment: There is a gap between removing system sound an all sound. Consider delete this answer